# Why can't I pull w/ TortoiseGit w/o entering a password?

Tags: windows-10, git, tortoise-git, pull

Some time ago I had to reinstall my work PC, following migration from Win 7 to Win 10. Previously I had a perfectly working setup of Git, using the Cygwin command and TortoiseGit in parallel.

After the reinstallation, I can no longer perform the `git pull` action from the TortoiseGit GUI, as it requires me to enter the server's password:

[image]

The pull requests made from the Cygwin CLI work just fine. Also, other operations from the TortoiseGit menu, like checkout, revert, show log, etc. work fine.

In the previous setup (Win 7) I was never required to enter the server's password, and I am not even sure how to obtain it, if it is even possible in our organization.

What is the reason I can't pull using TortoiseGit?

Comment: Have you verified if you clicked the "remember my conditionals" checkbox when you reconfigured your installation?

Comment: @Ramhound - I am not sure what you're talking about. Is it a one time settings I was supposed to do during reinstallation? Did you mean "credentials"?

Comment: Yes; I did mean credentials

Comment: Since it was quite some time ago (I just got used to use the CLI), I don't really remember having to put in my credentials. I thought the SSH key files should take care for that. And given all the other operations (that I checked) work fine, I don't understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGitPlink is used as SSH client by default. Therefore, you need to either configure PuTTY to use a special key (by using PuTTY sessions as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183147/3906760 and the [TortoiseGit FAQ](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html)) or load your key in PuTTY Agent (pageant) before performing a remote action.

Apart from using TortoiseGitPlink, you can also use use SSH from OpenSSH (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115724/3906760).